# <a>-tag name attribute not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, html

i made a link from one page to another page specific part.
here is my Example :
first page

```
 <a href="mypage.html#tips">tips</a>
```

another page

```
 <a name="tips">my tips</a>
```

it works fine in Ffox but not working in IE8.
what should i do.

Comment: "not working", how?  Does it even take you to the page, etc?

Comment: Is the anchor name "tips" unique on that page?

Comment: yes it was but wasn't detect <a name="tips">tips</a> but now it is working fine with <a id="tips">tips</a>.

Comment: @Ask4Tec:  Please don't forget to "accept" an answer here.  You have not accepted anything on any of your questions yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using an ID instead (make sure it's unique on that page)

```
<a id="tips">my tips</a>
```

This seems to be the standard now though I'm not sure why `name` isn't working for you as AFAIK it hasn't been deprecated.

### Update

What DOCTYPE are you using? Seems the `name` attribute has been marked "Obsolete" in HTML5. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete-but-conforming-features

Comment: thanks but it still not working i am using <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/html1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: @Ask4Tec I think you'll have to place an example somewhere online.

Comment: Thanks it works. i clear my cache in ie8 it works fine with <a id="tips">tips</a>.

Comment: @Ask4Tec In that case, it would probably work with `name` too though as mentioned, you're future proofing by using `id`

Answer (score 1):

This is a long established html standard that most certainly works in ie8.  For example, point IE8 to [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_contents) and then click on the links in the contents box.

I would suggest that the problem is somewhere else in your code or with the link itself being to an invalid page.  Some things to check;

- Use `<a id="tips">my tips</a>` instead.
- Is there more than one element with the document with tips as the id or name?
- If all of the page is displayed within the window with no scroll bar, then the page won't scroll to your tips section.
- If the anchor is on the same page that your link is on, simply us `<a href="#tips">` instead.

Comment: Seems like the anchor is on another page. Great tip regarding the short page though!